# How to limit queries for geospatial data?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, mongodb, geolocation

I am making an application that creates and populates a Google Map with markers based on objects with geocoordinates in MongoDb. However, I do so by checking if there are any markers within the window every time the map is changed in any way. However, this queries the server and database way more than I'd like and as such I want to find a way to limit these queries.

I was thinking that I could get the markers in a distance of the bounds of the map + 1 radians to begin with. Then if the adjusted center+distance exceeds the original center+distance+1 then the Client will query the server for new markers. However, I can't seem to wrap my head around the math of doing this. I already have the math for getting the radius for the bounds of the map shown.

More specifically I guess would be how would I determine (with the least processing power/memory usage) in javascript when circle A (with center (x,y) and radius (r)) and circle B (with center (w,z) and radius (o)) intersect.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to work with circles. A map usually is not a circle, when you work with a rectangle instead(defined by LatLngBounds) you may use the built-in methods(e.g. `LatLngBounds.intersects()`  or `latLngBounds.contains()`)

Comment: The reason I work with circles is to call the mongodb geolocation near method. which uses the coordinates you give with a radius to get locations within that radius.